# Discord.Net SendMessageAsync without command

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm making a program that most of the time runs without a person sitting infront of the PC. I thought it would be nice if this program could send you a PM on Discord if something happens that needs to be done manualy. So the User sets his name and #number in a config and the program PMs this person if something happens. So i set everything up and the Discordbot works as long as it uses the MessageRecieved-Event. I tried using the Ready-Event but this does not work.

My "Start"-Code:

```
public async Task startDiscordBot(string DiscordName, string DiscordID, string DiscordMessage)
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

    setDiscordID(DiscordID); // Sets the #Number of the User
    setDiscordMessage(DiscordMessage); // Sets the Message to be send
    setDiscordName(DiscordName); // Sets the Name of the User

    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

Edit: My current function is something like this:

```
public Task Notification() // not working
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

    IUser user = _client.GetUser(Name, ID); // Get the User <--- Returns null
    MessageBox.Show($"{user}"); // For debug
    IDMChannel channel = (IDMChannel)user.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync(); // Get a DM Channel
    channel.SendMessageAsync(Message); // Send a DM

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: User data is not always present at `Ready`. Also, try [`GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync(RequestOptions)`](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketUser.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketUser_GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync_Discord_RequestOptions_) to dm users

Comment: What you have will work **as long as the user is in cache**

Comment: How do i get the user in the cache? I also tried to use `GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync()` but `GetUser` returns null every time. I tried to wait 60sec after the Ready-Event fired, i tried waiting 5min after the Bot has started. Everytime the `_client.GetUser(Name,Number)` returns "null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Anwser. First of all thanks for the help. I was able to shrink down my code quite a bit.

```
public async Task startDiscordBot()
{
    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, Token);
    await _client.StartAsync();
}

public async Task Notification(string message) // Working
{
    IUser user = _client.GetUser(Name, ID); // Get the User (wait atleast 10sec after starting)
    var channel = await user.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync(); // Get/Create a DM Channel
    await channel.SendMessageAsync(message); // Send a DM
}
```

This wouldnt work ... well every solution wouldnt work because you need to enable **"SERVER MEMBERS INTENT"** on the Discord Developer Portal. You can find it under the Bot section.